# Can we access user input value in customfilter.Trying to access user input number from controller or directly in customfilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

I am new to angular js .Here I am trying to filter data based on the temperature by subtracting the user input(x) from the currentTemp variable.But not sure if i could access the user input value in custom filter.I am planning use same thing  on date later on.For now this might suffice.Please provide feedback on the possiblities of doing this using the custome filer(using input value and subtracting it in custom filter).Any other logic would also be very helpful.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qzne7wfnSa2keRcvbUUV?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('tempfilter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.sensordata = [{name:'Rob',"Date": "2014-02-16T00:00:00.000Z","Temp":42},
  {name:'Bob',"Date": "2012-02-16T20:27:11.507Z","Temp":50},
  {name:'Tom',
  "Date": "2012-02-16T20:27:11.507Z","Temp":60},
  {name:'Sinclair',"Date": "2012-02-16T20:27:11.507Z","Temp":65}];
  $scope.condEqual=function(){
  
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
  
});

app.filter('tempo', function() {
    return function( items, field ) {
 

      var filtered = [];
   var x=2;
      var currentTemp=62;
        
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if (item[field]<= currentTemp){
          filtered.push(item);
        }
      });
      return filtered;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tempfilter">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DateFilter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 
</head>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="2">
<button ng-click="condEqual()">Enter</button> </br>
<p id="demo"></p>
   Filtered list:
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="s in sensordata | tempo:'Temp'">{{s.Date|date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
      {{s.name}}
   {{s.Temp}}

    </li>
    </ul>
 
 Full List:
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="s in sensordata ">{{s.Date|date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
      {{s.name}}
   {{s.Temp}}

    </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

(The main thing i am trying to do here is filter the data based on date i.e.based on user input i.e if user inputs certain value e.g.3 i should be able to subtract the value from current date and display all the data 3 days from now.
i.e user inputs 3  and today's date 2/19/2015..I will filter all data from last three day).For now trying with the temperature will use the same logic for dates later on

Comment: Just use `ng-model` passing the same object property as an argument to your filter. Also, in Angular a line with `document.getElementById` is a big code smell, you should never fiddle with the DOM outside of directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
```

You should do:

```
$scope.filter = { value: 2 };
```

And instead of:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

You should do (in the HTML):

```
<input type="number" id="myNumber" ng-model="filter.value">

<p id="demo">{{ filter.value }}</p>
```

You don't need the button or the `condEqual` function, Angular two way databinding will update everything in real time.

The final bit, just pass `filter.value` as a parameter to your filter.

```
app.filter('tempo', function() {
    return function(items, field, value) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if (item[field] <= value){
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

And:

```
<li ng-repeat="s in sensordata | tempo:'Temp':filter.value">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot confused with  the last part where to pass filter.value in custom filter argument?..being new to angular is not easy.

Comment: No problem, welcome to stackoverflow. See this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwmJxzMXGHRsS8HwMJDi?p=preview) - it is inside `ng-repeat` where you can pass a second value to the filter using another `:` like this: `tempo:'Temp':filter.value`. Also note the function taking a 3rd parameter: `function(items, field, value)`.

Comment: Have you tried that [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwmJxzMXGHRsS8HwMJDi?p=preview), is it working as you expect?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help that was great.Was looking to figure this thing out for few days now.Now i need to figure out how to do the same thing with dates.i need to filter data for all dates less than the user value that was the main purpose,trying out with temperature to check the logic.Will try to figure that out tommorrow..Will use stackoverflow for queries from now on..:D

Comment: yea the plucker is working as expected i wanted to substract the user entered value. so that i could use the same functionality for date to filter data based on user input just like for temperature..but you had already given the main logic i just substracted the value.http://plnkr.co/edit/Qzne7wfnSa2keRcvbUUV?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Bind your input with a model then you can directly pass that model inside your custom filter like below

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="s in sensordata | tempo:'Temp':myNumber">{{s.Date|date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
      {{s.name}}
      {{s.Temp}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to set default value to your input then you can initialize your model inside your controller as `$scope.myNumber=62`

**OR**

You can define a function in your controller and use that function as filter just like below:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="s in sensordata | filter:filterByTempo('Temp',myNumber)">{{s.Date|date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
      {{s.name}}
      {{s.Temp}}

    </li>
    </ul>
```

**Filter Function**

```
$scope.filterByTempo = function(field,tempo) {
    return function(item) {
      if (item[field]<= tempo){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vZjSjYZfUwPYWwvPoKRF?p=preview) (Using Angular Custom Filter)

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eidvw15bsc0R3HttV4ap?p=preview) (Using filter Function)

Comment: Thanks a lot that works too...Was looking for the samething with date...User inputs the value and i could substract the todays days - user input days and get the requireddat......I had to subtract the value to achieve that...the logic u gave works..........var filtered = [];
      var x=60-tempo;
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if (item[field]<= x){
          filtered.push(item);
        }
      });
      return filtered;
    };
});